# useEffect hook was not getting called and useState hook didn't set its initial value when using useNavigate to navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

So I created a spinner like this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropagateLoader from "react-spinners/PropagateLoader";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const SpinnerLoading = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  console.log(loading); // the first console.log

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
    console.log(loading); // the second
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <PropagateLoader
          color="#36d7b7"
          cssOverride={{
            display: "block",
            position: "fixed",
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }}>
          {children}
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SpinnerLoading;
```

I wrapped it around the element that I wanted to use the spinner on

```
<Route path="/" element={<SpinnerLoading><Homepage /></SpinnerLoading>} />
```

**Problem:**

**1.** When I reload the page, the spinner works perfectly. However, when I use `useNavigate` to navigate to a page that is wrapped by this spinner, the children is loaded immediately, the spinner doesn't show up.

**2** You can see I have put 2 `console.log` statements to analyze the situation. When I reload the page manually, both 2 `console.log` are getting called. However, when I programmatically redirect to that page, only the first `console.log` is called, and it returns **false**.

Why doesn't the `useEffect` get called? And why does the `console.log` return false even thought I have set it to be true at the start?

**Expectation**
I want the spinner component to be loaded when using `useNavigate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Router will try to optimize as much as possible what is rendered. If you are rendering several routes with content wrapped in this `SpinnerLoading` component then a possible solution is to give each "instance" of it a unique React key.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <SpinnerLoading key={0}>
        <Homepage />
      </SpinnerLoading>
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/other"
    element={
      <SpinnerLoading key={1}>
        <OtherPage />
      </SpinnerLoading>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit useeffect-hook-was-not-getting-called-and-usestate-hook-didnt-set-its-initial-v]

Alternatively you could rework `SpinnerLoading` to be a layout route component that renders an `Outlet` and resets the `loading` state when the route changes.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import PropagateLoader from "react-spinners/PropagateLoader";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const SpinnerLoading = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <PropagateLoader
          color="#36d7b7"
          cssOverride={{
            display: "block",
            position: "fixed",
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }}>
          <Outlet />
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<SpinnerLoading />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    <Route path="/other" element={<OtherPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit useeffect-hook-was-not-getting-called-and-usestate-hook-didnt-set-its-initial-v (forked)]